# Ajax request giving error in rails aplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application I am making an ajax request as 
    $.ajaxSetup({
            url: '/get_paypal_button'
          });

```
      var dataToSend = { fundraiser_id: <%= @fundraiser.id %>,  
        amount:  $("#amount").val(),
        currency: $('#donor_donation_currency').val(),
        comment: $('#donor_donation_comment').val(),
        anonymous: $("#donor_donation_anonymous").is(":checked"),
        donor_email: $('#email').val(),
        donor_name: $('#name').val(),
        donor_city: $('#city').val(),
        donor_country: $('#country').val() };

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'JSON',
        async: true,
        data:dataToSend,
        success: function(json){
          $('#id_amount').val(json.amount);
          $('#custom_content').val(json.custom);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          console.dir(xhr);
          console.dir(thrownError);
        }
      });
```

In controller I am handling the data as

```
def get_paypal_button
  @fundraiser = Fundraiser.where(:id => params[:fundraiser_id]).last
  if params[:currency] == 'INR'
         amount_in_sgd = params[:amount].to_f/@fundraiser.sgd_to_inr.to_f
  elsif params[:currency] == 'USD'
         amount_in_sgd = params[:amount].to_f*@fundraiser.usd_to_sgd.to_f
  else
         amount_in_sgd = params[:amount].to_f
  end

  puts '----------finding donor-------------'
  @donor = Donor.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:donor_email])
  @donor.update_attributes(:name => params[:donor_name], :city => params[:donor_city], :country => params[:donor_country])
  custom = @donor.id.to_s + "::" + params[:anonymous].to_s + "::" + params[:comment].to_s

  @hash = {:amount => amount_in_sgd, :custom => custom}.to_json
  respond_with(@hash) do |format|
    format.json { render :json =>  @hash }
  end
```

end

when I use debugger and get the value of @hash it gives (which is correct)

```
"{\"amount\":15.0,\"custom\":\"2::false::\"}"
```

but the ajax request is executing the code which I have written in case of error and it is getting empty response.

I have tried everything and completely clueless because the similar code was working few days ago.

Comment: I see you use `.to_json` on your hash - you don’t need to call this.

Comment: I tried that too but still getting empty response :(

Comment: would it help to use lower case json in the datatype?

Comment: not affected by the upper case or lower case

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `format` is not set as you expect:

Check the `Accepts header` coming from the browser as part of the Ajax call. You can see it in the network tab of Firebug.

Or dump `format` to the log and check it.

Comment: that is also proper. Find the complete header below:

Request URL:http://localhost:3000/get_paypal_button
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/fundraisers/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
fundraiser_id:1
amount:13
currency:SGD
comment:
anonymous:false
donor_email:a@a.com

Comment: other than this ::
{readyState 0, responseText "", status 0, statusText, "error"}